# Track events in Reactjs pages and components globally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, refluxjs

I need to listen to following events and do action accordingly

1. Form submit event - if the form submission is successful, I need to broadcast success event `Added Name Record` and submit the data along with it to 3rd party service. If not, I need to broadcast a failed event say `Name submission failed` along with where the error occurred.
2. Page visit/Route Change - Self explanatory
3. Click events - Can be from list item click and button click. In case of list item need to pass item details and in case of button just the name  maybe
4. Searches - Any searches made should fire the event sending the keyword.

I am using React - 0.13 and Reflux store.

How can I  approach towards it to handle the events at a global level and without writing code at each button click/submit event/search etc ?

What is the best approach ? Body handler won't be enough I feel for this level of customisation required!

P.S - When I say broadcast let's assume that I have a 3rd party function call to make instead.

Answer (score 1):

Purely React ways:

Create base components to globally handle events with extensible event handling methods:

```
const MyForm = ({ onSubmit, children, ...props }) => (
  <form {...props} onSubmit={evt => {
    // do global handling
    onSubmit(evt);
  }}>
    {children}
  </form>
);

//use case
const CustomForm = () => (
  <MyForm onSubmit={evt => /* custom handling */}>
    {/* CustomForm inputs and such */}
  </MyForm>
)
```

Alternatively, you could take the HOC approach and wrap each handler you need:

```
const MyFormHOC = FormComponent => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      const { onSubmit, ...props } = this.props;
      return (
        <FormComponent {...props} onSubmit={evt => {
          // do global handling
          onSubmit(evt);
        }}/>
    }
  }
};

//use case
let CustomForm = ({ onSubmit, ...props }) => (
  <form onSubmit={evt => onSubmit(evt)}>
    {/* CustomForm inputs and such */}
  </form>
);
CustomForm = MyForm(CustomForm);
```

Downside to HOC approach is that your components need to pass along the event handler to the DOM element that will ultimately call it.

You could go one step further and create a single base component or HOC that handles all of your global events and then start using that as needed on your other components. It would need to know which props are supported by what components, though (e.g., `onSubmit` doesn't belong on anything besides a `form`).

Comment: I am using React.createClass() to do stuff. So not sure about HOC approach. In the last line, I feel you are hinting about custom button which can handle props when used like <CustomButton name='Add Record' handler={this.handler} /> and then do something on it

Comment: However, I am facing challenges and was not sure of I am using the best approach. I will get back with other challenges using single component(Custom Button)  approach.

Comment: [Higher Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) are functions that accept and return Components, so the output of `React.createClass()` would work fine with a HOC. The idea is to provide functionality for cross-cutting concerns, which means problems that are shared across multiple Components. In my example, you have multiple Form Components, each of which would need the same 'submit' functionality. Rinse and repeat for each event enumerated in your post.